# Switch to using network drive instead of personal Drive on cmd prompt

Tags: cmd.exe

I'm new to command prompt. trying to use it to rename files in batch. i figured out code, but have to move all files to the personal drive on my computer in lieu of the network drive. need help figuring out how to point it first to the network drive to proceed as needed.

default folder (listed as \servername\User in my explorer) listed is
U:>

i need to switch it to \servername listed on explorer as
V:

any direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For this from the command prompt `cd /d V:` will change your working directory to V:.

`cd /d V:\servername` will put you in the directory V:\servername.

Comment: awesome - worked perfectly. thanks so much!

Comment: No problem! Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest command to change disks is `disk:`.

For disks U and V this will be:

```
V:
U:
```

This will not change the last-used folder. So the following sequence
will not put you at the root of V:

```
V:
cd folder
U:
V:
```

But if you have not gone into a sub-folder as above,
you will remain on the root folder for the following sequence:

```
V:
U:
V:
```